# Does UIWebView in iOS 3 not support webkit column layout?

Tags: iphone, layout, uiwebview, webkit

I am using -webkit-column- ... css properties to accomplish nice line breaks in my UIWebView:

```
   #content {
    height: 460px;
    -webkit-column-width: 320px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
    }
```

This way text lines wraps from page to page without being cut off in the middle (book style).

It works perfectly from the iOS 4.x, but not in iOS 3.x (3.0, 3.1). 
Where can I find detailed UIWebView changelog of supported css attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing, double checking and runing the same styles with iOS 4 - it looks this CSS properties got support from 4.x up only.